# Installing Dropbox locally with home directory on NFS

Tags: linux, dropbox, symbolic-link, nfs

I'm in a shared compute environment at work, and for good reason IT doesn't want my Dropbox folder to be on the NFS.

My Ubuntu desktop's home drive (/homes/mylastname) is on NFS, but I have fast local storage, so I've moved my Dropbox folder there (/local/mylastname/Dropbox). I created a symlink from /local/mylastname/Dropbox to /homes/mylastname/Dropbox

The problem is that no matter what I do, I keep ending up with a .dropbox-dist folder in my NFS home drive, and this folder seems to be used by Dropbox a lot, adversely affecting network performance. I've tried moving this folder to local storage and creating a symlink, but Dropbox somehow ends up renaming this (in my home drive at the moment I have .dropbox-dist-old-YDh0D8 and .dropbox-dist-old-ZNlNE0) and then recreating a folder on NFS called .dropbox-dist rather than just continuing to use the symlinked folder.

Anyone successfully installed Dropbox entirely outside of their home directory?

I should say that I'm using both the graphical interface for Dropbox and the CLI interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to to start dropbox and make it think that your home folder
is not in the default location, try to start it with something like :

```
HOME=/path/to/pseudo-home-folder /path/to/dropboxd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dropbox exclusively via [this](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) script called *Dropbox-uploader*, which in fact is a commandline interface with various functions including download, sharing, etc. In other words, I've not installed the original Dropbox software/daemon at all, so it can't mess around with my home directory. I guess this qualifies as "entirely outside of their home directory"?

Dropbox-uploader uses the official Dropbox API, so you need to register it as a App on your Dropbox homepage. It also makes uploading/download files explicit, no accidental uploading/downloading in the background (IT will also like this).

Answer (score 0):

I use Dropbox on a spare drive and put all my Portable Apps (tons) in there.   You can move the folder and change root store easily, but normally you Browse to select remote folder (Advanced option )

After you install the Dropbox client on your PC/Mac/Linux machine, some users complain about Dropbox syncing and notifying them about all activity in the Dropbox. You can avoid these issues by adjusting your settings.

```
•  Disable Auto Sync.

•  Disable Notifications.

•  Do not install the local Dropbox client and use the Dropbox website.
```

You can still use your Dropbox locally and you can manually sync any time you wish. If you like to drop a file into your Dropbox on your Mac and grab it on your PC  or remotely elsewhere, then installing the client locally is advised. However, you can always access anything in your Dropboxes by going to the website. You can even use another user's computer to do this.